How to Sync Microsoft Access Appointment Fields with the Outlook Calender using Visual Basic
I need to create a link between an Access Database and Outlook for appointments.
I have a form in which I can enter all appointment details such as subject and date for example. I created a Macro that runs my coded function everytime the database updates (AfterUpdate) and I used the following code:
Public Function SyncWithOutlook()
    Dim objOL As Object
    Dim olNS As Object
    Dim olFolder As Object
    Dim olAppt As Object
    Dim olApptExists As Boolean

    ' Create Outlook Application object
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' Get the MAPI namespace
    Set olNS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' Get the default Calendar folder
    Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    ' Check if Appointment already exists
    For Each olAppt In olFolder.Items
        If Me.subject.text = olAppt.subject Then
            ' Appointment already exists, update its properties
            olAppt.subject = Me.subject.text
            olAppt.startDate = Me.startDate.Value
            olAppt.endDate = Me.endDate.Value
            olAppt.location = Me.location.text
            olAppt.AllDayEvent = Me.chkAllDay
            olAppt.Save
            olApptExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next olAppt

    ' If appointment doesn't exist, create a new one
    If Not olApptExists Then
        Set olAppt = olFolder.Items.Add
        With olAppt
            .subject = Me.subject.text
            .startDate = Me.startDate.Value
            .endDate = Me.endDate.Value
            .location = Me.location.text
            .AllDayEvent = Me.chkAllDay
            .Save
        End With
    End If

    ' Clean up
    Set olAppt = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set olApptExists = Nothing
End Function

I also made sure to include the Outlook object database but if I enter an appointment in the database nothing happens. Any idea what the issue could be?
I allready tried different Versions of the same Code, also tried to find if there's an issue with any object variable in the Code but I couldn't find anything

There is working code in the answers here

Never loop through all items in a folder (you wouldn't run a SELECT without WHERE, would you?) - use MAPIFolder.Items.Find

If you "enter an appointment in the database nothing happens" perhaps AfterUpdate does not trigger. Do you hit a breakpoint in Public Function SyncWithOutlook()?

Outlook sometimes has trouble with true DateTime values. So try with string expressions:
olAppt.startDate = Format(Me.startDate.Value, "Short Date") & " " & Format(Me.startDate.Value, "Short Time")
olAppt.endDate = Format(Me.endDate.Value, "Short Date") & " " & Format(Me.endDate.Value, "Short Time")

